# CVS keeps adding code at the end of the file I want to commit

Tags: version-control, cvs

I have trouble with 4 files in my CVS project. Each time I commit one of those files, CVS keeps adding the same line of code at the end of it. This line of code is a repeated line of the current file (but not the last line of it).

I've try several things : update, delete lines and commit, delete all lines and commit, adding lines and commit, adding header and commit. But I always get the same line of code added to the end of my file. I could delete all files and recreate those, but I would lost all my history data.

I find it awkward that CVS is modifying my file when I commit. Is it not counter productive as it may add errors in a compliant code?

I could add that my file is a .strings (text file, unicode). I'm working on a branch, but recently merge it in the trunk.

#### More Details:

- I'm using TortoiseSVN on a virtual Windows machine, which has access to my Documents folder of Mac OS X via a Network Drive between those two.
- It turns out that my colleague, which has the same project but on a real Windows folder, could commit without any problem.
- And now that he done that, the problem is solve for me too.
- But I have no idea what happen. My only clue would be a hidden character in Mac OS X that would breaks TortoiseSVN. Is it possible?

Comment: Hi. Thank you! I was really not sure if my question was better on SO or Programmers. But it is true that re-reading the faq makes me thing that it better fit on SO. I will flag it.

Comment: The obvious question is: what is different about those four files from those that work fine? What line keeps getting added? If at all possible, please post an example.

Comment: A data point: I've never seen that kind of behavior in many years of using CVS. But I don't branch and merge very often. What does `cvs status filename` tell you?

Comment: It tells me the file is up-to-date, Working revision 1.1.2.7 and repository revision 1.1.2.7. Expansion option : ukv. Also tells me that it is in the branch.

Comment: You are going to have to be much more explicit. This is not any behavior I have encountered with CVS and I branch and merge all the time.

Comment: @LokiAstari You are right, I didn't give enought details to solve this problem. My setup is pretty complicated : I'm using TortoiseSVN on a virtual Windows machine, which has access to my Documents folder of Mac OS X via a Network Drive between those two. It turns out that my colleague, which has the same project but on a real Windows folder, could commit without any problem. And now that he done that, the problem is solve for me too. But I have no idea what happen. My only clue would be a hidden character in Mac OS X that would breaks TortoiseSVN. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't experienced this issue with CVS, but note that you mention that the file you are editing is Unicode text (you don't mention if this means UTF8 or UTF16, but either can cause issues).

Depending on how your CVS server was built, and how (and on what platform) it is being run, it is highly possible that the server is *not* Unicode-aware.  This can cause a whole range of possible issues, including expanding RCS-style $ tags in places where the second (or later) byte of a Unicode character is equal to ASCII '$'.

The workaround for this is to mark Unicode source files as binary objects.  From the command line, this can be done using

```
cvs add -kb file-name
```

when adding a new file, or

```
cvs admin -kb file-name
```

for an existing file (replace *file-name* with the name of your file).

In the latter case, I'd recommend removing the (local copy of the) file and running 'cvs update' to get it back after changing the type.

Note that doing this is unlikely to help with changes you're already seeing in the file, so make sure to check the file, and fix any existing problem after making this change.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! It was a tough one, and I couldn't guess it! And your fix seems to work for now!